# Is there a built-in Haskell equivalent for C++'s std::bind2nd?

Tags: haskell, bind2nd

What I'm missing is the ability to partially apply the second argument of a function rather than the first.  This is especially useful when I want to pass the function to something like map, but without having to write a lambda for it each time.

I wrote my own function for this (definition below, just in case there indeed isn't any built-in function for this and anyone else was curious), but I would really like to know if there already exists something in the Prelude for this idiom as I prefer to reuse rather than reinvent.

Here is my definition and a trivial example:

```
bind2nd :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
bind2nd f b = \a -> f a b

foo :: Int -> Bool -> String
foo n b | b = show n
        | otherwise = "blabla"

alwaysN :: Int -> String
alwaysN = bind2nd foo True
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called [`flip`](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/flip_f.html).

Example:

```
Prelude> flip (-) 2 3
1
```

For future reference, it could have been found by simply searching [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) for the type signature in your question, namely [(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c)+-%3E+b+-%3E+a+-%3E+c). :-)